# Can't make a png image that has transparent background

Tags: gimp, transparency

I want to make a transparent image, so I made image's background transparent like this.

[image: Gimp Edit]

But exported PNG image was not transparent, it was kind of gray.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you viewing that exported file?

Comment: You still have some grey in the "wannabe" transparent areas you need to remove.

Comment: My five cents. Can you tell us something about the application used to display the PNG exported image? Is possible that the background of the application (e.g. a Browser or something else) is set to gray? What kind of background are you expected to see? Can you post somewhere your PNG?

Comment: @Scott Thanks! That is exactly the problem! I didn't noticed there is still gray color in the transparent area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove an overlay of grey to an alpha channel as is the case of the example we have to remove the alpha channel (*Layer > Transparency > Remove Alpha Channel*) first.

We then can convert the background gray back to alpha by choosing *Layer > Transparency > Color to Alpha*.

In the window that opens click on the color bar (defaults to white) to open the color selection tool. We can now either manually select a color or use the *Select Eyedropper Tool* to select the grey background color:

[image]

After conversion your background will be 100% transparent

[image]

but alas on putting this on a dark background we can see that some pixels coming from anti-aliasing at the borders of the red font will retain their original grey:

[image]

To avoid this we need to take care to work on a 100% transparent background in the first place.